# finding the locus of sphere?

Tags: geometry

A moving plane passes through a fixed point (a, b, c) (which is not the
origin) and meets the coordinate axes at the points A, B and C, all away
from the origin O. Find the locus of the centre of the sphere passing through
the points O, A, B and C.

i was trying this question many times  i could not get it. i m so much confused that  all the coordinates point are   away from the origin. From the origin i can take the distance formula ,  but  i don't know  where i have to start  and i have no any idea about this question

If anybody help me i would be very thankful to him, thank u

Comment: If you transform the problem from 3D to 2D you can get some more insight. It becomes the problem to find the locus of the center of the circles circumscribed to a right triangle and it results to be an hyperbola $y = \frac{{bx}}{{2x - a}}$.

Answer (score 0):

Extending a 2D solution, the center of the sphere should have coordinates 
$O_s=\left( {\frac{A}{2},\frac{B}{2},\frac{C}{2}} \right)$
where $A$, $B$, $C$ are the non-zero coordinates of the intersection points of the plane with the axes.

But $A$, $B$ and $C$ are not independent since the plane must pass through the $(a,b,c)$ fixed point. So the equation $\frac{a}{A} + \frac{b}{B} + \frac{c}{C} = 1$ must be satisfied.

Deriving $C$ from above equation we have $C = \frac{c}{{1 - \frac{a}{A} - \frac{b}{B}}}$.

We can get easily from the parametric equation (with parameters $A$ and $B$) of the position of the center to an explicit equation that should be
$$z = \frac{{cxy}}{{2xy - ay - bx}}$$
Probably some sort of hyperboloid...

Comment: The word "hyperboloid" is reserved for a certain kind of **quadric** surface, which this one is not. Also, $c$ seems to be lost on the way. Other than that, everything looks right.

Comment: you're right I had lost the c. I've corrected the formula

Comment: $C\left({A\over2},{B\over2},{C\over2}\right)$ makes no sense. What is "it"?

Comment: $\left( {\frac{A}{2},\frac{B}{2},\frac{C}{2}} \right)$ are the coordinates of the center of the sphere. I've corrected the previous post since, as you noted,  naming this point $C$ was a mistake and could create confusion when $C$ was already defined with a different meaning